# GTSAM install failed

Tags: cmake, installation, make-install

i had tried and search over google but there is no solution for this.
could somebody tell me how to fix this.
machine: ubuntu 16.04

```
ipin@LT-061-2017-OCT:~/gtsam/gtsam-3.2.1/build$ make install
    [  2%] Built target CppUnitLite
    [  9%] Built target wrap_lib
    [ 11%] Built target wrap
    [ 14%] Building CXX object gtsam/CMakeFiles/gtsam.dir/inference/Ordering.cpp.o
    In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/set.hpp:26:0,
                     from /home/ipin/gtsam/gtsam-3.2.1/gtsam/base/FastSet.h:30,
                     from /home/ipin/gtsam/gtsam-3.2.1/gtsam/inference/Ordering.h:24,


        from /home/ipin/gtsam/gtsam-3.2.1/gtsam/inference/Ordering.cpp:23:
    /usr/include/boost/serialization/detail/stack_constructor.hpp: In constructor ‘boost::serialization::detail::stack_construct<Archive, T>::stack_construct(Archiv
    e&, unsigned int)’:
    /usr/include/boost/serialization/detail/stack_constructor.hpp:54:9: error: ‘load_construct_data_adl’ is not a member of ‘boost::serialization’
             boost::serialization::load_construct_data_adl(
             ^
    gtsam/CMakeFiles/gtsam.dir/build.make:974: recipe for target 'gtsam/CMakeFiles/gtsam.dir/inference/Ordering.cpp.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [gtsam/CMakeFiles/gtsam.dir/inference/Ordering.cpp.o] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:719: recipe for target 'gtsam/CMakeFiles/gtsam.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [gtsam/CMakeFiles/gtsam.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Too old/too new Boost library, probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of absence of

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
```

It has been fixed in gstam by this [pull-request](https://bitbucket.org/gtborg/gtsam/pull-requests/264/fix-compile-error-with-boost-158/diff).